# Assigning the address to an email in c#

Tags: c#, email

I need an email component for my final project in intro to programming. Just doing something simple, and the code I copied from my more complex email client had to be modified, and I'm having an issue with a line of it.

```
myMail.To.Add = new MailAddress(txtAddress.Text);
```

That's what I'm trying right now. Getting:

> Error 1   Cannot assign to 'Add' because it is a 'method
>   group'    C:\ADixon\Final\Binary
>   Project\BinaryClock\BinaryClock\Form1.cs  567 21  BinaryClock

Just want it to send the email to whatever's in the box... although thinking about it, maybe I'd be better off locking it into a listbox with a "set email" button... either way, I'd think I'd need this basic code to work. Off to work on my "set email" button and new listbox!

Answer (score 1):

[`MailAddressCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a method. Nor a property, neither a field.

You just need to

```
myMail.To.Add(txtAddress.Text);
```